# Who invented the sun-synchronous orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, history, sun-synchronous

I was explaining sun-synchronous orbits to a co-worker and he asked me who invented it and when. I could not find an answer on wikipedia or a quick google search, so I thought about asking here.

Comment: That was Arthur C. Clarke who 'invented' the communications satellite @uhoh

Comment: It looks like the orbit was conceived around 1960, but I don't see anything about the people involved.

Comment: [Samos 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samos_2) in 1961 was launched into a sun-synchronous orbit, so the original conception of the orbit may have been protected information.

Comment: @GdD for some reason I randomly interpose those two names, like lose and loose, its and it's. Clarke and Asimov, their practically indistinguishable, no? :-)

Comment: @uhoh: I don't think it was Clarke. He certainly is at least one of the independent inventors (and perhaps the only one) of geosynchronous orbits, but they're not quite the same thing.

Comment: @tfb I've heard that Clarke was able to think of several different things, one does not necessarily exclude the other. Trying to invent a lightbulb does not exclude one from trying to invent a phonograph. It's not a binary choice. But if he was really focused only on long distance communication then a low orbit that needed to avoid frequent eclipses would not have been of interest I suppose.

Comment: I've never heard of Clarke being involved in the development of sun-sync orbits.  Just geosync.  My gut tends to agree with @called2voyage - the original development likely was classified.  Gray's ["Treatise on Gyrostatics and Rotational Motion"](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZZEKAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=orbit&f=false) laid out a lot of the math for it back in 1918, but I don't see a reference to sun-sync per se

Comment: @uhoh: I've heard that too.  However the papers he actually wrote were all about geosynchronous orbits, so that's all we can assume.  Certainly he may have had the idea of sun-synchronous orbits but if he never told anyone of it, then there's no useful sense in which he invented it, I think.

Comment: Is "Invented" the right word here?

Comment: Sun-synchronous orbits are a very non-trivial concept to me. Much more than geostationary orbits. It's taken some knowledge of orbital perturbation and some insight to realize it can be put to use.

Comment: @daniel - Invented vs Discovered is a whole different discussion :)

Comment: @Daniel Considering certain orbits are (sort of) patented, I think "invented" does reflect the way society treats it.